# What do we say when a person doesn't support someone in need?

Tags: phrase-request, phrases

When a friend doesn't stand by his friend in need, what expression do we use for it?
I'm particularly looking for a phrasal verb. The sentence should be in positive form, as I've already written the negative form "not stand by someone". It should be like "run away/turn someone's face away/close the doors".

Comment: He left him high and dry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to say support is no longer being given

> **turn their back on
>
>   turn away** (from)
>   **disappear
>
>   ignore
>
>   neglect**  *(particularly used with children and pets)*
>   **stopped taking his calls**  *(another way of saying ignore)*
>   **blanked** *(can also mean ignore)*

usage may also depend on context, examples

> The supporters of the President have **turned their backs on** the latest proposals
>   When the homeless man asked for money, people just **turned away**
>   When she needed him the most, he just **disappeared**
>   All his pleas for help were **ignored**
>   The starving cat was left at home and **neglected** for a week.
>   The agent who had been so helpful, recently **stopped taking my calls**
>   When I asked for help, he **blanked** as if he didn't know what I was talking about

Comment: When talking about someone in need, I'd say they turn their back **on** that person, not *to* that person.

Comment: Yes, it should be "turn their back on someone".

Answer (score 3):

You could also use ***desert***, even though it's not a phrasal verb.

<sub>(Note that *desert* is a bit different from *ignore*. The word *desert* implies "leaving"; with *ignore*, one might stay but pretend that they do not see or notice the need. This word may not be the best choice on all occasions; I added this answer because I think *desert* could fit many instances of such an occasion you described in the question.)</sub>

---

From Macmillan:

> **[desert](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/desert_2)**
>   [transitive] to leave someone in a situation where they have no help or support
>   *a story in which a woman deserts her husband*

Some examples around the web:

> He took off on a joint mission with another RAF fighter pilot, but, when he saw a flock of enemy planes nearby, he **deserted** his friend.
>   --*[In the Zone: The Twilight World of Rod Serling](https://books.google.com/books?isbn=0879727306)* by Peter Wolfe, page 143.
>
> He left his friend in the water for more than eight hours while he went back to his room. He **deserted** his friend in time of need.
>   --['Deserted Friend'](https://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=1368&dat=19690813&id=nZhRAAAAIBAJ&sjid=IBEEAAAAIBAJ&pg=4117,2560833&hl=en). *The Milwaukee Sentinel* - Aug 13, 1969.

Comment: You've suggested a nice word!

Answer (score 1):

"turn a blind eye" See [***turn a blind eye***](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/turn-a-blind-eye).

Also "left me in a/the lurch". See [***leave someone in the lurch***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/leave_someone_in_the_lurch).